# Which protocol to use if communicate with simatic plc over tcp/ip

Tags: networking, tcp, plc, libnodave

I am using [libnodave](http://libnodave.sourceforge.net/) and [s7netplus](https://github.com/killnine/s7netplus) to read and write data blocks to my simatic s7-300.
Everything is working fine but I want to understand how libnodave or s7netplus are workingso that I can implement something similar in c++ or c# myself based on plain tcp/ip sockets, just for fun.
On the library websites or source code itself I could not find any information about how they are implemented only that they are using tcp/ip sockets (I know in libnodave you can also use other ways but for now I am only focused on tcp/ip).
On my researches on other websites I found that I can use open tcp/ip or modbus tcp/ip.
But I could not really find any specifications related to simatic s7-300 which are telling me how to establish a connection or what to send to start a data transfer....
Please don't understand me wrong.
For example for modbus tcp/ip itself I can find specifications but these specifications are not telling me anything about what to send to the plc if I want to read 10 bytes from data block 17 or write 3 bytes to data block 1.

So my question is which possibilities on top of tcp/ip I have to exchange data from a pc with my plc and where I can find exact specifications related to simatic s7-300?

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Answer (score 0):

The communication protocol to a Siemens PLC is discribed on the site of Snap7.
http://snap7.sourceforge.net/siemens_comm.html

(Maybe better to use [Snap7](http://snap7.sourceforge.net/) instead of Libnodave for support of newer PLC's!)

Comment: But S7 Protocol is not open documented so there are no specifications aviable.